# What replaces input type=email with just user name text field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know where is this validation is coming from. I believe its from `BootStrap`. This is all fine for me.

But My Input type is not `email`, its just a `username`. I just want show same validation popup like `password` validation. like `Please fill out this field`.

So `What input type I have to use for username textbox to get show same validation popup`?

```
 <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required="" autofocus="">
 <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
 <label class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
 </label>
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I feel *really* old now :( `<crochety-old-man-voice>`Back in my day, we only had **ten** input types!`</crochety-old-man-voice>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is the line that you are talking about:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required="" autofocus="">
```

Since you already have `required=""`, you can simply change `type="email"` to `type="text"`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User name" required="" autofocus="">
```